# Xml parsing with many elements

Tags: php, sql, xml

I am not good at these advanced XML - I had to change affiliate companies and they use a completely different format. To save space I put the section of XML I am having issues with on pastbin here:
https://pastebin.com/4HjML08T

My old one did not use many elements, however the new one does. here is the call

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/games.xml');
```

Have most of it pulled to my SQL DB, however having stubborn a prob pulling the info I want. I was able to pull the titles of topics which are:

all-games (which are the total games in the library)
[this will list all the gameid's in the library about 1500+]

arcade
[id's of each game under this category]
rating-hit

So I can grab all those headings with

```
foreach($xml->Languages->Language[0]->Catalogs->Catalog[0]->Dictionaries->Dictionary[$i] as $title){
        echo($title['Code'].'<br/>');
```

This will print_r with:
all-games
genre
reating-hit

My issue is I cannot seem to pull the id's of the genre.

I THOUGHT this worked,

```
foreach($xml->Languages->Language[0]->Catalogs->Catalog[0]->Dictionaries->Dictionary[$i]->DictionaryItem->Elements->Element as $g){         
                echo $g['ID'].'<br/>';
```

but it produces all the same id's for all the genres. So I am guessing I am not getting the correct id's from each of the genre

What I do with these XML is I run nightly and have it parsed to sql, this allows faster access to objects to display on my webpage, and easy to switch templates. Again, not really good at XML. But just need a little push to export these (genre, all games, rating) to a text file.

Thank you VERY much for any assistance. I have been trying all kinds of methods and internet search for various ways to get these elements to come up correctly.

***E D I T: (ADDED FULL SCRIPT)***

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/games.xml');
    for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {  // GO THROUGH 3 GENRE TITLES - ALL GAMES, GENRES AND TOP GAMES
        foreach($xml->Languages->Language[0]->Catalogs->Catalog[0]->Dictionaries->Dictionary[$i] as $title){
            
            echo($title['Code'].'<br/>');           
            $list = "";
            
            // AFTER GETTING THE ABOVE, LIST ALL THE GAME ID'S FOR THIS TOPIC AND ADD IT.
            
            foreach($xml->Languages->Language[0]->Catalogs->Catalog[0]->Dictionaries->Dictionary[$i]->DictionaryItem->Elements->Element as $g){         
                $list .= $g['ID']."\n";
                echo $g['ID'].'<br/>';
                
            }
            // PUT IT INOT A TEXT FILE
            file_put_contents('data/'.$title['Code'].".txt",$list);
        }
    }
    /* =====================================================================================*/
    
    echo 'DONE';
```

Comment: Please provide fuller attempted code block and not isolated line snippets. In both loops, we don't know `$i`.

Comment: Hi. My apologies. Here is the whole script. It works, but doesnt provide the correct id's for each genre. ratings seem to have the corrent id's and the all-games are correct as well. the problem I get is that all the ids for each genre is identical, which I know is not correct.

Comment: With sample XML, I cannot reproduce your issue of *identical* genres ids. Print outs reflect unique Element IDs like XML. I refactored by using `$title` in inner loop: https://rextester.com/HBUY77127

Comment: OK, so just to understand. the 2nd foreach loop should actually use the $title? I was close? I am in the process of taknig xml classes. Looks like this lang might be around for awhile. I'll run the new script and see how it works. Thank you very much for taking time to look at this!!

EDIT!
It produced the desired results!! Is there a way to give credit to you for your answer?

Comment: Is `<Languages>` really the root of your actual XML? Your Pastebin sample is cut off at the end. If it is the root, `$xml->Languages` should return a non-object since `$xml` is the root element and so retrieving other element should raise errors, never mind any identical results printed.

Comment: `<PARENT_CO_EXPORT> <-- Name changed to prevent adv. plug
 <Options/>
 <Languages>
  <Language Code="en">`

This is the rest of it, just tow other tags

Comment: Ok. Other than that root difference, I made no fix to your original code. By *refactoring*, I simply mean making a synonymous change where using `$title` in inner loop cuts down repetition. Your original set up should return same results. Again, unless I am misunderstanding your problem, I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ah, understood, well I can say with confidence I ran my code countless times, looked up some more solutions on various forums, and ran again, and yet it was all the same ID. I understand after checking the code, it should have produced the same results (even actually did a qb64 xml reader I wrote, and THAT worked.. so I just assumed the php code was in error. Regardless - I still thank you !